# verifiy json else throw error fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ExampleObject is an example of what is expected from api endpoint

```
let ExampleObject={
  "id":"",
  "name":"",
  "Body":""
}
```

how to make sure that the response has those keys without looping through the response? Response is a json object not an array

```
function handleError(err) {
  //handling error code based 
  return err
}

export const GetUsers = async({
  user,
  Following
}, Paging) => {

  try {

    const response = await fetch(Apiurl, {
      method: 'GET',
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': Token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })

    if (response.status != 200) {
      throw ('Error Sending request')
    }

    const ResponseArray = await response.json();
    //Verify object here
    if ('Key') {
      throw ('error with json')
    }
    return ResponseArray
    
  } catch (err) {
    throw (handleError(err))
  };
};
```

and then I call GetUsers from another module

```
async function callapi() {
  try {
    await GetUsers(Object, Paging)
  } catch (err) {

  }
}
```

Comment: `['id', 'name', 'body'].every(key => ExampleObject.hasOwnProperty(key))`

Comment: you can try using [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi). it will give you more control for the validation of response.

Comment: without looping .

Comment: Why is your requirement "without loop" - you could, of course, just expand @JaromandaX solution eg `if (!ResponseArray.hasOwnProperty("id") || !ResponseArray.hasOwnProperty("name") || !ResponseArray.hasOwnProperty("body"))` ... but why would you? And what if you add another 10, 20 properties?

Comment: Off topic: variable names help you know what they are.  If you name your variable `ResponseArray` then you should be able to assume it's an *array* without having to add disclaimers/comments everywhere "it's not an array".  Or is it actually an array in a JSON string?  How does `ExampleObject` relate to `ResponseArray`?  We've all assumed they're the same value.

Comment: @Abd you said _"without looping through the response"_ but the example given only loops through the required keys array

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if ("id" in ExampleObject && "name" in ExampleObject && "Body" in ExampleObject) {}`